# Sorting problem in .rdlc file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

this is my query's result :

```
klinikAdi                               SeanSayisi  SeansTarihi

Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2095    NİSAN 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2147    MAYIS 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2338    HAZİRAN 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2279    TEMMUZ 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   369     AĞUSTOS 2009
```

this is correct result. but the report viewer viewig that:

```
klinikAdi                               SeanSayisi  SeansTarihi

Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   369     AĞUSTOS 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2095    NİSAN 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2147    MAYIS 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2279    TEMMUZ 2009
Özel FMC Avcılar Diyaliz Merkezi ( 18001)   2338    HAZİRAN 2009
```

how can i stop sorting on reporviewer?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a sort expression set on one of the fields... Most likely the value column field in the middle.

Take a look at the properties of the table's column field.  You can right click on it in the report studio, and select properties.  In the properties window, is a Sorting tab.  Make sure that there are no expressions set in this section.

If you can't do that, you can also edit the RDLC file manually.  Search for SortExpression.
You can remove the entire  node, and it should take care of your problem.